# First character position and size in the browser by jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, position

By using selectors I can determine the offset and size of the element like this:

```
$("h1").width(), $("h1").height(), $("h1").offset()
```

Is there any way, without changing DOM, to do the same for the actually rendered first (or last) character in the element? Bonus: if it were working regardless of the structure of children.

That is, something like (but working, of course):

```
$("h1::first-letter").width()
```

The jQuery is not hard requirement, Javascript / BOM will do as well.

Comment: So, you mean get height and width of a specific letter in a word>?

Comment: Have you tried `.css("fontSize")`? Is the first letter at `h1` style adjusted at `css` using `:first-letter` pseudo class? What is expected result?

Comment: I mean the actually rendered character position (top, left) and size. It's actual extent, not something specified in CSS.

Comment: @JeremyRajan Yes, top, left, width, height of the first character inside h1.

Comment: So, the whole of h1 has the same css, no matter what?

Comment: CSS is irrelevant for this question. In the question, CSS is used to select the element / first character, nothing to do with getting desired info about actual rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get first character width of element then you can try this

And there is no required pseudo-selector (because all character has same font-size)

```
alert($("h1").css("font-size").replace("px",""))
```

Comment: Thank you for attempt, but the answer is not acceptable: it does not give actually rendered first symbol size because it assumes "all character has same font-size". Also, no information about height, top, left.